# jquery: calculate number of fitting divs and margin between them?

Tags: jquery, css, element

i have a bar in my footer called #elementbar.
i want this elementbar to have 30px wide colored squares in it. And those sqaures should have a margin between them around 10px.

what i wanna do now is calculate exactly the amount of elements that would fit in the width of the body. and i want to calculate the margin between them so the elements have exactly the same margin from start to end. now i have just manually set the margin in css but in this case very first element has a slightly different distance to the browseredge than the last one.

is there mathematical solution to calculate the fitting elements as well as the appropriate margin between them (the margin should always be around 5px to 10px)

```
#elementbar {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:15px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}

#elementbar .element {
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    float:left;
    /*margin:0px 5px 0px 5px;*/
}

#elementbar .element {
    margin:0px;
}
```

jquery:

```
function elementbar() {
    var bw = Math.round($('body').width());
    var num = Math.round(bw / 30); //one element is 30px wide
    for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        $("#elementbar").append("<div class='element'></div>");
    }
}
elementbar();
```

later i want also to call the function on resize so that whenever you resize the browser the appropriate number of elements gets appended to the elementbar.

any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="debug"></div>

var bw = $('.bar').width();
var num = Math.floor(bw/40); // Assume 30px width + 10px margin
var margin = Math.floor((bw - num*30)/(num-1));

for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
  $(".bar").append("<span class='block'>&nbsp;</span>");
}       
$('.block').css({ marginRight: margin + 'px'});
$('.block:last').css({ marginRight: '0px'});

$(".debug")
    .append("Width: " + bw +
            ", marginRight: " + margin +
            ", number: " + num);
```

See it in action: [jsfiddle.net/s4MGT/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/s4MGT/3/)

Comment: thank you, however in this case it doesn't quite work: http://www.jsfiddle.net/s4MGT/1/ my bar is 100% wide and i want them to spread equally with the body width. now the last element jumps into the next line.

Comment: It does work, you had made an error and were taking the with of the body instead of the width of the containing div.bar http://www.jsfiddle.net/s4MGT/3/ However, there was also a rounding issue, we need to take floor and not round to avoid overflow.

Comment: oh yeah, right! perfect. thank you very much. last question: any idea how i can append new objects when i resize the window. i always want to have the right amount of objects, also when i resize the window larger or smaller. can i save the current number of objects and on resize i check if the would fit in more or less and append or remove those objects?

Comment: Simply make a function out of this and call it in $(window).resize (see jQuery API documentation of that function). Don't forget to clear the div.bar content each time.